# An error in PHP Timeclock 1.04 relating to "Post Validation"

Tags: php, validation, post

I am not much of a programmer so bear with me here.  I have been trying to get PHP Timeclock 1.04 running on my server and have got most of it up and running but for some reason I cannot delete some of my timeclock entries.  It only effects some users, not all.  Basically I delete the time entry and it says "Time deleted successfully" but under that there is a message that says "Something is fishy here."

I have this in the offending code:

```
// begin post validation //

if (!empty($post_username)) {
$query = "select * from ".$db_prefix."employees where empfullname = '".$post_username."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$tmp_username = "".$row['empfullname']."";
}
if (!isset($tmp_username)) {echo "Something is fishy here.\n"; exit;}
}

if (!empty($display_name)) {
$query = "select * from ".$db_prefix."employees where empfullname = '".$post_username."' and displayname = '".$display_name."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$tmp_display_name = "".$row['displayname']."";
}
if (!isset($tmp_display_name)) {echo "Something is fishy here.\n"; exit;}
}

if (!empty($email_addy)) {
$query = "select * from ".$db_prefix."employees where empfullname = '".$post_username."' and email = '".$email_addy."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$tmp_email_addy = "".$row['email']."";
}
if (!isset($tmp_email_addy)) {echo "Something is fishy here.\n"; exit;}
}

if (!empty($office_name)) {
$query = "select * from ".$db_prefix."employees where empfullname = '".$post_username."' and office = '".$office_name."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$tmp_office_name = "".$row['office']."";
}
if (!isset($tmp_office_name)) {echo "Something is fishy here.\n"; exit;}
}

if (!empty($group_name)) {
$query = "select * from ".$db_prefix."employees where empfullname = '".$post_username."' and groups = '".$group_name."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$tmp_group_name = "".$row['groups']."";
}
if (!isset($tmp_group_name)) {echo "Something is fishy here.\n"; exit;}
}

if (($admin_perms != '0') && ($admin_perms != '1')) {echo "Something is fishy here.\n"; exit;}
if (($reports_perms != '0') && ($reports_perms != '1')) {echo "Something is fishy here.\n"; exit;}
if (($time_admin_perms != '0') && ($time_admin_perms != '1')) {echo "Something is fishy here.\n"; exit;}
if ((isset($delete_data)) && ($delete_data != '1')) {echo "Something is fishy here.\n"; exit;}

// end post validation //
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: This application looks not well written and I bet it can be prone to SQL injetion attacks. Error message "Something is fishy here" is also an example how to not write app, because it can be triggered by each of the blocks and is not helpful at all. First change error messages to something like `"Error: $tmp_email_addy not set "` for the first block, `"Error: $tmp_office_name not set"` for second and so on.

Comment: This is not an application, but code snippet of that application. Dude, you should learn how to code things before you start writing applications